# SAS: ID variable based on several conditions

Tags: sas

I have following dataset:

```
ID      Status   
1       cake
1       cake
1       flower
2       flower
2       flower
3       cake
3       flower
4       cake
4       cake
4       cake
```

Basically, I am only interested in the observations that, grouped by the ID, include at least one flower. Also I want an indication of whether the observation grouped by ID only has flower or if it was cake too. E.g. I would ideally like something like:

```
ID      Status      Indicator
1       cake        1
1       cake        1
1       flower      1
2       flower      2
2       flower      2
3       cake        1
3       flower      1
4       cake        0
4       cake        0
4       cake        0
```

I have tried to subset the dataset in multiple ways and merge together, conditional on the ID, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: please include your code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SAS data step based on your input (which I called test here) will return that indicator value by ID group.

```
proc sort data=test;
by ID descending status;
run;

data result(drop=status);
set test;
by ID;
retain indicator;
if first.ID then indicator=0;
if status='flower' and indicator=0 then indicator=2;
if status='cake' and indicator=2 then indicator=1;
if last.ID then output;
run;
```

You could join that result with the source data to get the result as you provided it in your post.

NOTE: I don't have enough reputation to comment on the answer provided by Gordon Linoff but I just want to point out that there the indicator will not take three values (`0='no flower'`,`1='cake+flower'`,`2='only flower'`) but will instead be a count of the number of 'flower' entries per ID, which I don't think is quite what the poster is asking for.

Rewritten as follows will give the expected result with indicator values `0='no flower'`,`1='only flower'`,`2='cake+flower'`

```
proc sql;
  select t.*,
         (count(distinct status))*(sum(case when status = 'flower' then 1 else 0 end)>0) as indicator
  from test t
  group by id;
;
quit;
```

Comment: I did something similar to this earlier, but the problem is that it only gives the indicator variable a value if last.id=1, so the rest of the observations are given 0 as value although they should be categorized as 1 or 2.

Comment: @Karen Larsen Like I mentioned, joining this result with your source table will give you the result as you listed it in your original post. Otherwise, I added an edit with the "corrected" version of Gordon Linoff's answer (where the meaning of  values 1 and 2 of indicator are swapped from what you posted).

Comment: Thank you a lot!
I am running the code now, but it seems like my computer is having problems, which is probably related to the dataset containing 2,5 mio. observations. 
By any chance, do you know a code that requires less of the computer?

Comment: @KarenLarsen I personally get better performance by running the "data step" solution and joining with the source than by running the "proc sql" solution; but they were both pretty efficient on my local machine. If you are running the SQL solution, you might want to add a `create table` statement at the beginning of the query as SAS otherwise creates a report output which takes significantly longer than creating a table output.

Answer (score 1):

`proc sql` comes to mind:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*, tt.indicator
    from t join
         (select id, sum(case when status = 'flower' then 1 else 0 end) as indicator
          from t
          group by id
         ) tt
         on tt.id = t.id;
```

`proc sql` also has a "remerge" extension to SQL.  That allows you to do:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*, tt.indicator,
           sum(case when status = 'flower' then 1 else 0 end) as indicator
    from t j
    group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is already sorted by ID then you could use a double DOW loop. The first loop will check for the presence of the values. Then you can use another loop to write back all of the detail rows for that group.

```
data want ;
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    if status='flower' then _flower=1;
    else if status='cake' then _cake=1;
  end;
  if _flower and _cake then indicator=1;
  else if _flower then indicator=2;
  else indicator=0;
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

This should be fast assuming the data is already sorted.